# trying to create an algorithm similar to an approximate subset-sum table in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, math

I've been trying to construct an algorithm in PHP that in some ways resembles a subset-sum problem, but in this case, i'm not looking for an exact match, only the closest matches, as in most cases there is unlikely to be an exact match.

Let me elaborate in a little more detail. Say I own various hypothetical investments, and need to raise the sum X from existing investments. Say X = 40000.

The array of inputs are (4500, 8750, 12900) and the number of each held are (8, 10, 10).

Now, I can intuitively work out that 4500 * 8 = 36000, 12900 * 3 = 38700, but a closer match would be (4500 * 6) + 12900 = 39900.

I soon found that try to loop through each possible combination rapidly creates 10's of million of possible arrays, even more if additional inputs are added. That would not be a problem if it was just for my own purposes, but not viable for a web-application.

I'm not asking for anybody to write code for me. I'm not a mathematician, so I'm just wondering if there is a different way I could tackle this problem, or are least short-cut parts of it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's a well known problem called the "Knapsack Problem" that can be solved with a dynamic programming approach.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: Hi, I thought knapsack problems are kind of "3-Dimensional", as they involve weight and the as the size, while this is only "2-Dimensional", as I'm only really concerned with the values. Am I slightly missing the point ? (Quite possibly...)

Comment: You are correct but you can easily convert your problem into a 3D problem by setting the weight of every value to it's value (e.g. `4500` would have a value of `4500` and a weight of `4500`).

Comment: Hi, I've also got an interlinked issue.

In this case, using the same values as above, I also need to do a second calculation, assuming a tax-free amount of £29,250 (as an example) can be taken. So I need to work out work out how to take the balance (£10,750) in the most efficient way, but in this instance, it must not be LESS than 10750, so effectively I'm trying to work out the smallest amount to take over and above 10750. So given the original values of 4500,8750 and 12900, the answer is clearly 1 x 12900. 

I take it I could reverse the calculation ?